# Local dedicated hosting space (own hardware)

Tags: hosting

Where can I find local dedicated hosting space for my own hardware?

I know I can rent dedicated hosting from various companies online, but usually I think that means I'm renting their hardware too. I just need a space with a network connection and a power outlet. That's it. How much would this cost? What would I search for? Is it available easily? Or would it only be the sort of thing huge companies would do? I'm in the greater NYC area.

It's for a project I'm working on, but the thing's loud and annoying. I'd be willing to pay a little to get it out of sight and out of mind. I don't even care too much about the quality of the network connection. I'd rather not rent other people's hardware cause it probably would cost a fortune to rent a machine like this (tons of ram).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Colocation facility. They are all over the place, I would just search google for one near you. Most facilities rent as little as 1/8 of a rack.

The price is going to vary depending on how much space you rent, as well as what additional services you need.

**Edit**
Missed that you where looking in the NYC area. We use Peer 1's Colocation facilities in the Financial district for the SO Servers

Answer (score 2):

It's called colocation, search for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a specific recommendation around NYC, I've used [Xand](http://www.xand.com) in Hawthorne, NY in the past.  It's a little bit of a hike from NYC, but you can take the Metro North to the Hawthorne station (just past White Plains) and then a cab to their facility.  The trip is less than an hour from Grand Central.  They are very friendly and helpful and had very good prices when I was working with them (around 2006).

The company I worked for at the time rented two cabinets at Xand and we filled them with our own equipment.  That included redundant power and a dedicated T3 for our disaster recovery backup.  No problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Equinix has multiple facilities in the greater NYC area: 
   http://www.equinix.com/data-center-locations/map/equinix-north-america/new-york-data-center/
2. As does Internap:  http://www.internap.com/wp-content/uploads/111-8th-Ave-Data-Center-Tour-091310.swf
3. I think Speakeasy does as well.

---

I have personal experience with 1 & 2 and a colleague once used Speakeasy.